# Replace connections function in visual basic to get file path

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, filepath

I have script in visual basic that check if file exist:

```
Try
        Dim myVariable As Variables
        Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("FileExist", myVariable)
        myVariable("FileExist").Value = _
        System.IO.File.Exists(Dts.Connections("Export Students").ConnectionString)
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
    Catch
        Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Failure
    End Try


  Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
```

and I need change it so that did not contain the function "Connections". Is any other way to get file path? All examples that I found was with "Connections" function.

"Export Students" is label for file in conections manager in ISP Project.

Comment: This is not [tag:VBA]..

Comment: Errr, what exactly is the variable `Dts`?

Comment: @JeffBridgman The Dts object is an instance of the ScriptObjectModel class